# Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: res/drawable-ldpi/ic_launcher.png

Tags: android, jar, duplicates, apk

I have a simple Android application that uses a JAR I have built. When trying to generate the final archive I get the above error. While exporting the JAR I excluded AndroidManifest.xml. I tried cleaning the project and removing ic_launcher.png from the JAR but then I received an error when trying to build the JAR. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your JAR file **must not** contain same files as in your main project. Rename **ic_launcher.png** to something else.

Comment: @Nitesh Verma because after compiling all res files are "merged" in one R file where all id's are stored. If two files have the same name it means they have same id which leads to conflict.